# Information on OOP, creating Objects

Tags: oop, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a problem in understanding OOP...
This is it :

Sometime's you create an object with this syntax:

```
Object ObjectName = new Object();
```

But sometimes, we don't need to do that like in Android:

```
Textview TextviewName;
```

Or in J2ME:

```
form formName;
```

I already searched it and I got some information (but not sure) that this is because of static method... is it true? I think it has a relation with Polymorphism.. is it true?
Thanks all.

PS : Sory if I made some mistakes, English is not my native languange :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget static methods - they're not relevant here. I'd advocate only looking at static methods / elements when you've truly grasped what objects are.

In Java, you can do this:

```
Object object;
```

Just as well as you can do this:

```
Object object = new Object();
```

In the first example, you're creating a reference but you're not populating that reference with anything, in the second example you're creating a reference and populating it with a new object, on which you can call methods, modify values and so on.

If you try and call methods on the first declaration you won't be able to - there's nothing there. Depending on the language and how you've declared it this might produce an error at runtime or a compile time error (Java does both depending on whether it's a field or a local variable.) The principle though is the same for all OO languages, you can't dereference (call methods, fields, etc.) on a reference that hasn't been populated, because in effect you're trying to call a method on something that isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Your Textview would not be initialized. Any try at using it would result in a NullReference error. In order for an object to actually be created, you have to use the new syntax or a function that returns a valid object.

However, this is a syntax-dependent issue, so first decide what language you want to study. If  your Textview had been declared in C++, it would actually create an object, on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

you  are mixing different languages and it's not the case of static methods nor polymorphism..
i suggest to read a good  book of OOP beginning with the basis.. you can find "Thinking in c++" for free on the net..